# Set cell value based on comparison of two different cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to compare two rows from a column and output it to another column.  In a sense, I have the final score to a game with each team listed on the row with other stats.  I want to create a column that labels the winner "W" and the loser "L".

I've attempted
`df2.iloc[0, 3].where(df2.iloc[0, 2] > df2.iloc[1, 2], 'W', inplace = True)`
and
`df2.iloc[0, 3] = df2.where(df2.iloc[0, 2] > df2.iloc[1, 2], df.iloc[0, 3] =='W', inplace = True)`

The two most common errors I've run into among other attempts are:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'where'
and
ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self

```
Tm  H/A  Final W/L/T
SFO   A     16     T
NYG   H     13     T
```

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('20020905_nyg_scoring.csv', header = 0, index_col = 0)
df1.drop(['Detail', 'Quarter', 'Time', 'Tm'], axis = 1, inplace = True)

df2 = pd.read_csv('20020905_nyg_team_stats.csv', header = 0, index_col = 1)
df2.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis = 1, inplace = True)
df2 = df2.transpose()
df2.reset_index(inplace = True)
df2.rename(columns = {'index':'Tm'}, inplace = True)
df2.insert(1, 'H/A', ['A', 'H'])
df2.insert(2, 'Final', (df1.iloc[-1, 0], df1.iloc[-1, 1]))
df2.insert(3, 'W/L/T', 'T')
pd.to_numeric(df2['Final'])
df2.iloc[0, 3].where(df2.iloc[0, 2] > df2.iloc[1, 2], 'W', inplace = True)
print(df2)
```

Ultimately, the expected results should give me a W for the SFO line and an L for the NYG line under W/L/T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `np.where` to get `W` and `L` and an `if` statement to check whether it's tie or not, if it is it assigns `T`:

```
df['W/L/T'] = np.where(df['Final'] > df['Final'].shift(-1), 'W', 'L')
if (df['Final'].shift() == df['Final']).any():
    df['W/L/T'] = 'T'
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Tm H/A  Final W/L/T
0  SFO   A     16     W
1  NYG   H     13     L
```

Comment: That worked!  I was unfamiliar with .shift() and now have some reading to do!